# AirPods started to randomly bugging

Tags: ios, headphones, airpods

my AirPods Pro 1 Gen started to randomly (mostly after around 5 min) disconnect or they start sound like when the connection is bad even im directly around them. I didn’t dropped them or anything. Do you have any ideas what I could do ? (IOS 17.2 )

Comment: How old are they?  It could be a battery issue where there’s insufficient charge to properly function or the device could be dying of old age (it happens). Do you have access to another BT audio device to rule out the phone?

Comment: Also consider environment.  Has anything changed where you normally use them?  Added a microwave? (for instance)